# android firebase database using material search filter all child value

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, binary-search-tree

i am trying to search data from firebase database. but i don't know. here i attached my firebase database screenshot. 
In my firebase database, there are name, phone, datefrom and dateto that are present. I want to search data from that if I enter phone number. I want to get result that name,phone, datefrom and dateto.
give some example for search material.

[Firebase screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5U4wN.jpg)

**java**

```
public class ViewProduction extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private Adapater mAdapter;

private ProgressBar mprogress;

private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
private List<Datastore> mUploads;

private TextView date_filter;
Calendar mCurrentDate;
int day, month, year;

EditText edit;
Button btnsearch;

String searchPhoneNumber; //Added

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_production);



    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    edit =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);

    btnsearch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsearch);


    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("Production Details");

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerj);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mprogress = findViewById(R.id.progress);

    mUploads = new ArrayList<>();

    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Rajadriving");

    btnsearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            searchPhoneNumber = edit.getText().toString().trim();

        }
    });



    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    DatabaseReference dateRef = rootRef.child("Rajadriving").child("9-6-2018");
    Query query = dateRef.orderByChild("phone").equalTo("searchPhoneNumber");


    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Datastore upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Datastore.class);
                mUploads.add(upload);





            }


            mAdapter = new Adapater(ViewProduction.this, mUploads);

            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mprogress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



        }



        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(ViewProduction.this, databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mprogress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}





@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home){
        this.finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.udayaj.rajadriving.ViewProduction">




<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/table01"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerji">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

give some example for search material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, you need to use a query like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference dateRef = rootRef.child("Rajadriving").child("9-6-2018");
Query query = dateRef.orderByChild("phone").equalTo(searchedPhoneNumber);

for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    Datastore upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Datastore.class);
    mUploads.add(upload);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. i got it.

Comment: Good to hear that. Cheers!

Comment: Sir I need searchPhoneNumber example. I know edittext and one button using to search phone numbers. But I need Java code. Eg: if I enter phone numbers in edittext and i press search button. after I get a output.

Comment: You can get the text from the EditText like this: `String searchedPhoneNumber = editText.getText().toString().trim();`

Comment: Where I put this code. And what I do in button onclick.

Comment: Yes, you add a click listener and your button and inside the onClick method, you add this code.

Comment: Sir I already added. But searchedPhoneNumber can't resolve. equalTo(searchPhoneNumber).

Comment: Make search `searchPhoneNumber` as a global variable.

Comment: Sir I'm beginner to android Java. Please update my question. I request to you.

Comment: Sir I need your help.

Comment: I'm waiting for your reply.

Comment: I just updated your question by making the variable global. If you have further issues, please add another question so me and other users can help you.

Comment: Is right. Is the exact same thing as the other ones.

Comment: This sounds to be another problem which cannot be solved here. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: i know sir. but i reached my ask question limt.